# What’s the translation for” hope of it all”?

Tags: traduction, anglais, paroles-de-chanson

This line actually refers to one of my favorite songs “August” by taylor swift and the whole sentence is “ to live for the hope of it all”. I’ve already checked google translate but i don’t think that it’s accurate. One of the translations was “l'espérer, tout” and another one was “pour l'espoir de tout”. I don’t think that they’re accurate because when I retranslate the sentence it gives me different English meaning...

Comment: One of the translations was “l'espérer, tout” and another one was “pour l'espoir de tout”. I don’t think that they’re accurate because when i retranslate the sentence it gives me different english meaning. Also thank you for attention.

Comment: A translation of the lyrics is available [on the Internet](https://www.paroles.net/taylor-swift/paroles-august-traduction), and that phrase is translated as *vivre pour l'espoir de tout cela*, which Google Translate translates back as *live for the hope of it all.*  One warning, though — you are putting way too much trust in Google translate; *vivre pour l'espoir de tout* is not a bad translation, and the fact that it doesn't translate back to the exact original phrase is just in the nature of translations.

Answer (score 1):

The French translation of “to live for the hope of it all” could be

"vivre avec l'espérance que tout aille pour le mieux"

ou bien

"vivre avec l'espoir que tout se passe bien"

Comment: In English, there is a difference between "live for the hope of it all" and "live with the hope of it all." Il me semble qu'en français la même différence serait exprimée par « vivre pour l'espérance » et « vivre avec l'espérance ».

Comment: @Peter Shor Merci pour votre remarque. Il me semble néanmoins que "vivre pour l'espérance" est peu courant en français et d'une signification pas complètement claire.

Comment: La signification n'est pas claire en anglais non plus. Voyez ce [site](https://www.reddit.com/r/TaylorSwift/comments/10fs67w/meaning_of_to_live_for_the_hope_of_it_all_in_a/).